# Error reading json file in Docker Image running R

Tags: r, json, docker, docker-image, jsonlite

I'm trying to read a json file in R using jsonlite. When running in RStudio it runs correctly, but when running it through a Docker Image, I get the error message:

`Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text ../Project_Folder/my-sub-folder`

Here is the R code I'm running:

```
versionText = "ver.2.3"
data_filepath_wd = paste0("../Project_Folder/my-sub-folder-", versionText, "/")

metadata <- fromJSON(paste0(data_filepath_wd, "params.json"), flatten=TRUE)$variables
```

The file I'm trying to read is valid json but from the error message it doesn't appear to be reaching it correctly. How can I resolve the error?

Comment: How are you starting the docker container? What volumes/mounts are you using? Have you correctly set the container's `WORKDIR=` so that the relative path still works?

Comment: I'm running ```docker build``` followed by ```docker run```. I haven't set volumes/mounts/WORKDIR in my Dockerfile.

Comment: Things running *inside* a container do not (very much by design) have access to files *outside* of that running container. If you did not build it in to the image and you do not use volumes/mounts, then the only other way to get data is by network access. If you haven't configured that, then there is no data.